# getContent() not paging - only returns latest results

Tags: bolt-cms

Within an extension (JSON access), I'm calling getContent() with:

```
 $items = $this->app['storage']->getContent($contenttype, $options);

 $response = $this->app->json($items);
 return $response;
```

The options array is:

```
[
    'limit' => 5,
    'page'  => 3
]
```

But getContent only returns the latest 5 results, not calculating the offset from the `page` variable. Is there another setting that I have to change to get it to recognise the paging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling getContent you need to specify that you want paging turned on, here's some adding `'paging'=>true` to the options should work correctly.